# 502 Proxy Error (node.js + express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a bizarre error that only occurs on my production server. This code runs fine on my local development server, but trying to run it on production leaves me with a 502 Proxy Error:

```
$.getJSON("/joomla/sales-aggregate?start_date_unix=1416086500", function(sales_data) {
  alert(sales_data);
});
```

The endpoint for this request is an express app:

```
app.get('/joomla/sales-aggregate', function (req, res) { 

  var d = new Date();
  var start_date_unix = req.query.start_date_unix || Math.round(d.setDate(d.getDate()-30)/1000);
  console.log(start_date_unix);

  var options = {
    url: 'https://www.client-website.com/api/sales_aggregate.php?start_date_unix=' + start_date_unix,
    port: 80,
    method: 'GET',
    auth: {
      user: "****",
      password: "****"
    }
  };

  request(options, function(err, response, body) {
    res.json(JSON.parse(body));
  });
});
```

Why would this code work on development, yet return a Proxy Error on production?

Comment: Might be missing module you installed on you dev server but not on your prod server. You need to check the console of you express app which Error was thrown. If you don't see a message in console or the logs, then you might suppress it somewhere. If there is nothing at all then there might be configuration an error with the app that you use as proxy (e.g. `apache`, `nginx`, ...)

Comment: I ran 'npm install' on production.. Shouldn't that install the needed modules?

Comment: Only if you added them to your package, e.g. with `--save`, if you only installed with with e.g. `npm install express` without the `--save` option then it will not be automatically added to your `package.json`.

Comment: Hmm. Pretty sure I added everything to my package.json.. But I'll double-check.

Comment: Checked the modules I'm using against my `package.json` and they appear to be all there. Also, the error that my server is returning is `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u`, but I found out that's because `body` is returning `undefined`